# Uncaugt ReferenceError: ViewSwitcher is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to import a framework to the Avada Wordpress Theme but ran into some issues.

https://www.wecu.dk/bobboxy/

It gives me the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ViewSwitcher is not defined

Is it because jQuery conflicts or the jQuery version I'm using and how can I make it work?

I tried with

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

And added `$j` instead of `$`

This is the site I'm trying to import and combine with my theme. Here the `app.js` has no issues:

https://www.wecu.dk/bob

Best regards

Shane Madsen

Comment: You can make it work by reading the [**codex**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), it tells you how jQuery no-conflict wrappers should be done in Wordpress, and how you include scripts the proper way

Comment: Okay now I created a child theme and imported the script with the wp_enqueue_script function.. I still got the same error :(

Comment: Do you have other suggestions? :)